# When designing basic sites, should I use PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, html, adobe-edge

In the past, I have always used PHP for even my basic site design stuff, and I have never used  the .html extension. Several reasons for doing this, but one of the biggest ones was being able to use "PHP Includes" on my site, so I would only have to design my navigation once.

This worked fine, because Dreamweaver was always able to render basic PHP stuff that was not really "Server-side", like the includes. But now, I am trying to switch to using Adobe Edge Code, because it is truly lightweight and I don't have to load up a big application on slower computers to do work. It is also really nice, because it does have great CSS editing, and a wonderful live preview that just works in browser. From what I have found out, their is no way of doing the cooler stuff, when you are using .php files.

So - I guess my question is, Is it possible to do something like "PHP-Includes" only using HTML/CSS/JS? Or do I really need to stop being lazy and switch my workflow back to doing all HTML, and just Copy/Paste the nav sections on each page.

Also - sorry if this question is to much like a "Discussion", I tried to write it as straight forward as I could.

Edit: The application supports JavaScript, CSS, and HTML and, one of my friends is recommending jQuery. Anyone know how it would work with jQuery? Or if it would?

Comment: If you really can't use PHP with this application (which I find a little hard to believe), then it's not worth using.

Comment: @ChrisHerbert The app works with PHP, but its only opens it. Adobe Edge Code is truly for HTML5, CSS, and JS. Even Adobe says use Dreamweaver for anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vanilla HTML and CSS do not have any facility for includes natively.  The closest thing is server-parsed html (aka "shtml") which *can* do includes, but if you go that route, you may as well just go back to PHP (shtml has no advantages over PHP).

I think your choices are PHP or copy/paste, as you said.

Comment: Yea, SHTML will probably not work, because Edge wants just a straight .HTML file to actually work. I also have a discussion open on the Adobe Forums, maybe I can get some info there.

This seems like something HTML5 would have included by default. I mean, we have been including other image files onto a page for years, why can't we just include a .html page.

Comment: Would an iFrame work? I have heard of people using those before.

Comment: @David: yes, but iframes are so last millennium...

Comment: @godka Yea, I know. I have a friend who gave me a jQuery Script that might work. The application allows full working of jQuery and JS.

I'm also looking into PHPStorm - the application looks lightweight, but has PHP support.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatives to Server-side includes and PHP is to use a static site generator:
A script that takes your files (in HTML, Markdown or some other format) and combines them with other HTML and styling and finally returns a whole website consisting of HTML, JavaScript and CSS.

They exists in a lot of different formats and languages. The most popular is probably [Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll) (Ruby), but there are alternatives in PHP ([Phrozn](http://www.phrozn.info/en/)), Python ([Hyde](http://ringce.com/hyde)), Node.js ([Punch](http://laktek.github.com/punch/)), and many more.

Comment: Thanks, but the idea is sticking with just HTML/CSS/JS.

Comment: @David: And that's all you need to upload to your host. It's a script/framework which generates all the necessary HTML-files with all you headers and navigation on every page. Basically doing the copy/paste for you, but more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve the same thing as `include` by using [Server Side Includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes)

Answer (score 0):

There are other technologies such as Server-Side Includes (.shtml) -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes, but I'm totally unfamiliar with this Adobe platform or what it allows.